# Executing a python script using cron

Tags: python-3.x, cron

I have a python script which updates a database. The script reads the update values from another database. The database being read from is updated everyday hence my script needs to run everyday.

After executing crontab -e, then

```
* * * * * . $HOME/.profile; cd /home/lonwabolap/Dashboard/Web_application && /usr/bin/python3.6 sdb_access_update_night_info.py >> file.out
```

The file, 'file.out' is empty. The expected output is 'successful (today's date)'. Running it every minute is on purpose. It is intended to run at 8 am everyday. The path to the script is correct. My assumption is that since i used environmental variables for my database credentials it doesn't work.

Please help me find a way to make this script work

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you are using cd to go to the directory and not just call the script with the whole path? like ```/usr/bin/python3.6 /home/lonwabolap/Dashboard/Web_application/sdb_access_update_night_info.py```

Comment: Yes there is. The tutorial i was following was using this method.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2CNZGEH59Q&t=65s

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
* 8 * * * . $HOME/.profile; cd /home/lonwabolap/Dashboard/Web_application && /usr/bin/python3.6 sdb_access_update_night_info.py >> file.out
```